# How to simulate IllegalStateException on the emulator for new Background limitations

Tags: android, debugging, service, android-emulator, background-process

I noticed crashes of my app in Google Play for some new devices after I update my app to the targetSdkVersion 27.

The reason of crash was my call to start some TTS service in the Application object onCreate due to the new Background Execution Limits introduced in Oreo.
When startService(intent) is called IllegalStateException is thrown.

I'm trying to reproduce this error on the emulator with Android 8.1 (API 27). However it works with no problems.

I tried to set No background processes in Developer settings\Background process limit. But my app keeps working well on the emulator.

My service is running in the another process:

```
<service
    android:name=".services.Text2SpeechService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false"
    android:process="my.app.services.Text2SpeechService" />
```

QUESTION: how can I make the emulator to simulate this error?

Comment: Tell me how are you trying to reproduce this error? I reproduced this error by adding some dummy `App Shortcuts` programmatically (not by using xml method), registered them from `MainActivity`, and then placed `startService` command in `Application` class

Comment: I just want my app get crashed when I run it on the emulator. Just like experienced some of my users with new devices. 
Adding some test code into the app is not desirable.

Comment: Ya I wasnt able to reproduce it either.